# Get posts meta_query by repater field

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I'm currently using Advanced Custom Fields to fill a certain custom post type with rows of data. I'm trying to get these posts, but for some reason this doesn't work.

```
$tenten = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'tenten',
    'orderby'       => 'rand',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'tent_formaat_nummer',
                'value'     => $maatCode,
                'compare'   => '=',
                ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'tent_locatie_%_vanaf_datum',
                'compare'   => '!=',
                'value'     => '1234',

            ),
    )));
```

This is supposed to give me all posts, because there is no post with the '1234' value. However, no posts are returned.

Comment: what about your other condition?

Comment: Why there is the `%` in the key name: `tent_locatie_%_vanaf_datum`, maybe it is causing problems?

Comment: vanaf_datum is a subfield of the tent_locatie repeater field